# Does a player qualify as "club-grown" if he has been out on loan?

Tags: football-manager-2015

I am playing FM 15. I am currently having some trouble accommodating the 4 players to be registered for ECC who have to be club-grown (been in club for 3+ years between ages 15 and 21). So I was thinking of getting in a prodigious kid and then maybe loan him. Will this strategy let the kid be classified as club-grown after he returns from loan in the 3rd season, seeing that he didn't actually spend the 3 years at the parent club?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I kind of wish you hadn't put the name of the game in the title for the sake of hot network questions.

Comment: I don't know how that works. Care to clarify please?

Comment: Questions with a lot of traffic are often shown on the sidebar of other sites in the SE network. Arqade has a history of titles that are outright horrible without the context of a game. Without the game title in there, that would also be the case for your question ("When I buy a 17 yo kid and loan him out...")

Comment: Lol, goodness, no. I don't want to "buy" a 17 yo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to have something better to document than this [forum post](http://www.fm-base.co.uk/forum/football-manager-2015-players/284583-trained-club-home-grown-status.html), but what I do like about it is that it apparently both explains the logic behind the answer and also shows you how to confirm it.

The answer is no, the loan spell will prevent the player from accumulating time toward being club-grown ... if you loan him to another club in your nation, then his home-grown status will not be affected, but that's not really what you're asking about.

If you look at the player's status with his club, that should show the date on which he'll become home-grown. While he's on loan, that date will be pushed into the future; when you recall him, it should stay the same.

Here's an example from FM15 - I created a new game with just England, Large database, playable all the way down to Conference North/South. Below you can see Aleksandar Gogic, who's on loan at Boreham Wood. On 8 Aug 2014, he'll become club-grown at Reading on 26 July 2015.
[image: FM 2015 screenshot of Gogic on loan]

In the second screenshot, you can see I've advanced the game one week. On 15 Aug 2014, Gogic will become club-grown ... 2 Aug 2015, also one week later. So he cannot make progress toward being club grown while on loan from his club.
[image: FM 2015 screenshot of Gogic not becoming club-grown while on loan]